# Telecommute only or telecommute preferred option for candidate profile

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Instead of just `Open to telecommute`, it would be nice to have option of `Telecommute Preferred` or `Seeking Telecommute Position.`

Right now if only `Looking for a job` and `Telecommute` are checked, your profile says:

> Job search status: actively looking . You might also wish to indicate full-time vs part-time, telecommute, **or** willingness to relocate.

That message seems to be an error (see bolded `or`) because `Telecommute` is checked. And, the employer view does not seem to reflect that you may only be seeking a telecommute job. In fact, it shows nothing at all in this case for sought after position.

The only way to even show `Open to telecommute` is to have it in combination with full-time or contract position. This would certainly be true in most, if not all, cases.  However, if telecommute is the only way you want to work, you end up turning down local offers that do not allow telecommute.

You can search for jobs as `telecommute` only but you can't list yourself as `telecommute` only. Would be nice if you could.